# Sorted merkle tree versus rsa accumulator

Tags: rsa, certificates, performance, merkle-damgaard

When compared to sorted merkle tree and rsa accumulator, which one is the best? Rsa accumulator has constant proof and it adds/deletes at constant cost. What is the verification cost for rsa accumulator? I think rsa accumulator's adding operation is better than sorted merkle tree. Is that correct?